# issue when trying to integrate boostrap template to codeigniter 3.1.4

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

hello everyone I'm trying to integrate boostrap template into a codeigniter 3.1.4 project.  I have already put my boostrap asset folder into the codeigniter parent folder and when I create a new .htacces in that folder and test my website I have a burg from the navigator. please if anyone can give me the rigth way to do that it would be helpful for me I'm waiting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want to know how to integrate a boostrap template in codeigniter 3.1.4 project.

Comment: @ArseneLeVirtu-oseDjeukam - same way as you integrate any other html template in your project.

Comment: The boostrap css is not recognized